# My Toggle button on Nav Bar won't close in HTML?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, styles, toggle

I have a simple html page. The toggle button will show my menu, but after clicking it again, the menu won't close.
Toggle Code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand our_logo" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
```

I guess it might be conflict with my popup window function
pop up code:

```
<!--popupstart-->
<div id="popupbox" class="popup-graybox">
<section class="shopnow-popup-sec" style="background: #aadba6 url(/images/APP_popup_BG-01.png) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;" >
  <h2 data-edit="text">NEW APP</h2>
  <h3 data-edit="text">INSTALL NOW</h3>
  <h5 data-edit="text">Get Your weekly Flyer & Store News</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ample-food/id1523958538"><button  data-edit="button" type="submit" class="signupnow-btn">go ios now</button></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abei.zff"><button  data-edit="button" type="submit" class="signupnow-btn">go Android now</button></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<!--  <h6 data-edit="text">* Terms and Conditions Apply</h6>-->
  <button type="button" class="shopnow-popup-clsbtn close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</section>
</div>
<!--popupend-->
```

Style Component

```
.shopnow-popup-sec { 
        background: #9eddee; 
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; 
        width: 600px; 
        height: 600px; 
        margin: 30px auto; 
        padding: 0;  
        -webkit-background-size: cover; 
        -moz-background-size: cover; 
        -o-background-size: cover; 
        background-size: cover; 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        position: relative; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52); }
```

**If you can give a look， I'll be very appreciated.**

Comment: Can you share your full HTML, CSS code. The code doesn't have the other required classes used in the code.